# Clojure file-system portability

Tags: clojure, directory

I want to write a simple program for playing sound clips. I want to deploy it on Windows, Linux and MacOSX. The thing that still puzzles me is location of configuration file and folder with sound clips on different operating systems. I am a Clojure noob. I am aware that Common Lisp has special file-system portability library called CL-FAD. How it is being done in Closure? How can I write portable Clojure program with different file system conventions on different systems?

Comment: Have a look at http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.java.io-api.html

Comment: @Chiron: http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.java.io-api.html is a better URL. clojure.github.io is where the current docs are put, while the version in Rich Hickey's account is from version 1.1.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `clojure.java.io/file` to build paths in a (mostly) platform-neutral way, similarly to how you would with `os.path.join` in Python or `File.join` in Ruby.

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

;; On Linux
(def home "/home/jbm")
(io/file home "media" "music") ;=> #<File /home/jbm/media/music>

;; On Windows
(def home "c:\\home\\jbm")
(io/file home "media" "music") ;=> #<File c:\home\jbm\media\music>
```

`clojure.java.io/file` returns a [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). If you need to get back to a string you can always use `.getPath`:

```
(-> home
  (io/file "media" "music")
  (.getPath))
;=> /home/jbm/media/music"
```

Is that the sort of thing you had in mind?

In addition to [`clojure.java.io`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.java.io-api.html) (and, of course, the methods on `java.io.File`), [`raynes.fs`](https://github.com/Raynes/fs) is a popular file system utility library.

Comment: To get back a string you can also just use `(str path)`

Comment: What do you do if you use clojure on .net? Recode it to `clojurre.net.io` or something? There should be a clojure facility, which abstracts from such runtime dependencies, not?!

Answer (score 2):

Note that Windows perfectly supports the forward slash as a path separator (which is awesome because that way you don't have to escape backslashes all the time).

The only significant difficulty you'll run into is that the "standard" locations (home folder, etc.) are different on Windows and UNIX systems. So you need to get those from the system properties (see the `getProperty` method in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).

Comment: Kind of an underappreciated fact, making people use too many lines of code relying on the other answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

For a platform-independent approach, you can find the canonical path from a path relative to the project and then join it with the filename.

```
(:require [clojure.java.io :as io :refer [file]]))

(defn file-dir 
  "Returns canonical path of a given path"
  [path] 
  (.getCanonicalPath (io/file path))) 

(-> "./resources" ;; relative
  (file-dir)
  (io/file "filename.txt")) ;;=> /path/to/project/resources/filename.txt
```